# How can I align the hintText vertically of a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Something strange happens, for some reason I can't put the `hintText` vertically aligned inside the`TextField`, the strangest thing happens when the text field has focus (see gif). The `borderRadius` is lost and apparently at that moment it is fixed. When the focus of the text field is lost it gets messy again. How can I correct it?

this is my code:

```
Widget _searchBar() {
 return Container(
  height: 40,
  child: TextField(
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: _styles["gris_oscuro1"]["color"],
    ),
    onChanged: (value) {},
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: _styles["gris_claro"]["color"],
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
      hintText: "Buscar por código",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: _styles["gris_oscuro2"]["color"]),
      prefixIcon:
          Icon(Icons.search, color: _styles["gris_oscuro2"]["color"]),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(color: _styles["gris_claro"]["color"], width: 1.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


  Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    backgroundColor: _styles["fondo"]["bg"],
    drawer: MenuWidget(),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: _searchBar(),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: the same code is working perfectly for me. Which channel are you using? You can try `flutter clean` and then `flutter upgrade` first or please share the parent widget also.

Comment: Is it on a bottom sheet?

Comment: @SanjaySharma I updated my code..

Comment: @SanjaySharma I ran the commands you mentioned and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the code of `_searchBar()`?

Comment: I tried to reduce my code as much as possible so that you can see it better. I have updated it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the height you are giving to the parent Container. There can be two ways to align the hint text vertically,
(They are independent of each other, chose either one)

```
child: Container(
  // height: 48, //ONE - Remove the static height
  child: TextField(
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
    style: TextStyle(
      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    onChanged: (value) {},
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), //TWO - Specify the padding if you want your custom height.
      filled: true,
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
      hintText: "Buscar por código",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.red),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

1. Remove the Container's height
2. If you want to size the parent container according to your desire, you have to specify some inner padding for the content.

Edit: You will lose the border when you tap on the TextField as the you are not passing anything to the `focusedBorder` property of `TextField`. Follow the code below:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
  filled: true,
  alignLabelWithHint: true,
  hintText: "Buscar por código",
  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.red),
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
  ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder( //Add this to your code...
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand a little more about my problem. but another one still persists, and it happens when the text field has focus, the `borderRadius` is lost https://imgur.com/a/SlCQqJy

Comment: No issues, I am updating the answer.

Comment: @yavg Check the answer now.

Comment: can you help me please with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226635/what-to-do-to-avoid-the-error-that-an-image-is-not-found-on-the-web-this-freeze thank you